# Swift: Using Integer as field in struct

Tags: swift, struct

I am making a call to an API in Swift and I am using the JSONDecoder. The API call returns categories and ids, the problem I am having, is that it stores the subcategories under the key of the main categories id.

The returned data looks like this:

```
categories = {
  data = {
    main = (
      {
        id = 39;
        name = Electronics;
      }
    )
    sub = {
      39 =
        (
          {
            id = 49;
            name = TV;
          }
        )
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that `39`. In my structure I can't have `let 39:[Category]` or else I get the error:

> Expected patten.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: That isn't JSON...

Comment: That's what happens when I ```print(JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []))```

Comment: Are you sure? Because that's not valid JSON...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use 39 as a parameter name, but you can use this

```swift
    let category_39: [Category]
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case category_39 = "39"
    }
```

But i think this structure will be difficult, if a new Category added from server side there is no preDefined category id
i suggest to use the following model

```swift
struct Model: Codable {
    let main: [Category]
    let sub: [String: [Category]]
}
struct Category: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

and then get SubCategories by category id

```swift
let subCategories = model.sub[String(id)] // String(id) --> "39"
```